# Can Microsoft Edge's Web Select feature be done on other Chromium-based browsers?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, google-chrome-extensions, microsoft-edge, chromium

Microsoft Edge has this feature called Web Select (Ctrl+Shift+X) which allows you to highlight any part of a webpage, be it text and image, then lets you copy it. I really liked how they implemented it where it's almost like you're taking a screenshot by drawing a rectangle on the webpage and anything covered by the rectangle gets copied.

I was wondering if there's a way to do this with other Chromium-based browsers, either via extension or some developer tool?

Comment: There might be an extension that has similar features but the exact functionality you described at this time is an Edge only feature

Answer (score 3):

Web Select is a Microsoft invention, available only on Edge.

Perhaps you can do similarly using the Chrome extension
[Html Scan](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/html-scan/jkkccmdilclkdkhkfdmcbdiagpibmpne),
described as:

> Html Scan helps to copy html code, text  instantly in any webpages with one click.

Otherwise, to get the HTML would require using
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>
to get whole page source.
Or extract the HTML of a single object using the Developer Tools.

Comment: I'm not necessarily looking for the HTML source, but more being able to draw a rectangle to "select" almost any portion of a webpage to copy it.

Comment: Copy in what sense? If as an image, quite a few products can do that.